# Proper Java RTP/RTCP stack

Tags: java, stack, rtp

I've been struggling to find a decent RTP stack implementation **for Java**. JMF or FMJ are not options here as I don't want all the bells and whistles of codecs and audio/video capture; I just need to create RTP streams, dump data in them and read data from them.

I've been using [jlibrtp](https://wiki.cs.columbia.edu:8443/display/~hgs/jlibrtp+-+Java+RTP+Library) but its API is shady, logging is based on System.out and every now and then I get a couple of NPE's.

Also, RTCP support would be nice (again, I'd like to handle the control myself, I just need the API).

So to sum up:

- Clean API;
- "Manual" data handling;
- Decent logging;
- RTCP support;
- No dependencies;
- Optimised for server-side usage (many RTP sessions active at a given instant).

Is there such a library or will I have to code one? ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://github.com/jonbo372/efflux

It depends on Netty (for I/O) and SLF4J (for logging).

Comment: "efflux" is no longer supported. Site is down. Any alternatives?

Comment: @AndriiRubtsov Updated the link but it's a long-dead project. Could be interesting for educational purposes but I'd hardly recommend using it.

Comment: @biasedbit  does it works for remote connections too?

Comment: @AndriiRubtsov does it works for remote connections too?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the rtp stack of Mobicents.
This stack is part of media server but you can take it as separate module. http://code.google.com/p/mediaserver/

Inside the module you can find the tests that showing how to use it.